# Help please my rubber tree

Tags: plant-health, plant-care, pruning, growth

I am new here and I am reading lots of good advice.

I have had this plant for 7 years now and it’s been repotted 3 times, I’ve cut back many times where the arms are and the top but it never grows in the middle.

[image]

How can I get the middle of the branch to grow? Any help much appreciated.

Comment: The middle will never grow if that's where you cut the tops off. But your new plants can look more tree-like if you choose your cuttings well.

Answer (score 2):

To get more top growth you could stop repotting it as when you do that the plant spends time growing new roots.  Also, more light, much more light.

Outside light levels can be 100,000 lux. Inside a room away from a window can be 200 lux. When you move a plant inside or outside it needs time adjust to the new light levels and the usual response is dropping leaves.

To grow them indoors provide lots of overhead light. Fluorescents, LED, halogen, whatever you have but lots of it. Get a light meter to test the light levels.

Comment: Thank you that’s brilliant! Never thought of a light before but this time of year the room doesn’t get much light. I will be doing this for sure.

Comment: Ohhh one more question please. Would this survive outside?

Comment: @Emma It will grow outside in the right temperatures.  Tolerate as low as 5 deg C but better in the room temperature range  (18 deg C or ~68 deg F).  But to acclimate the plant you have to put it outside in deep shade for a week or so before exposing to full sun